# Android status bar icon requirements

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-statusbar

This is a follow up to [Android status bar icon color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641085/android-status-bar-icon-color-) posted 6 years ago.

**My question is how strict this guideline is handled by now (especially for the newer OSs) and if there have been any changes/relaxations to the rule?**

A lot of time has passed and the most recent OSs are not discussed under

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar

and

https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-notifications.html#

only mentions `monochrome`and `two-dimensional` as a property.

Thanks for your information.